# Как удалить экземпляр класса?

Tags: ruby, объекты, методы

Допустим я создаю класс и экземпляр класса.

```rb
class NewClass
  attr_accessor :arg1, :arg2
  def initialize(arg1, arg2)
    @arg1 = arg1
    @arg2 = arg2
  end
end
obj = NewClass.new(55, 3)
```

Как я теперь могу удалить этот обьект класса?

Comment: Что значит «удалить»?  Сборкой мусора занимается сборщик мусора.

Comment: Под словом удалить, я подразумеваю полностью удалить его(вместе с его аргументами) из класса (и из программы в целом), что бы потом к нему нельзя было обращаться))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *Ruby* отсутствует понятие «удаления» объекта.  Этим занимается
сборщик мусора.  Если у вас переменная `obj` является
единственной ссылкой на объект, то вам достаточно присвоить ей
`nil`:

```ruby
obj = nil
```

Сборщик мусора освободит ресурсы объекта по своему расписанию.

См. также: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/19523039/1892060.

Comment: А еще такой вопрос, не много не по теме, просто не хочу отдельным вопросом спрашивать. Можно ли как то, перезаписать параметры экземпляра? Т.е. , если взять пример выше, вначале присвоить обьекту параметры 55 и 3, а потом перезаписать их значения, и что бы в итоге обьект имел параметры не 55 и 3, а какие то другие цифры?

Comment: @SsPay _StackOverflow_ не форум, и отдельные вопросы лучше задавать отдельно.  Я рекомендую вам почитать хотя бы Мацумото, у него ответы на большинство ваших вопросов.  Вам же нужен `attr_accessor`.